# Cable stuck in Shimano twist grip shifter

Tags: grip-shifter

If anyone has any idea how to get the broken end of a cable out of a twist grip shifter mechanism I would love to hear them. The shifters are Shimano Revoshift. The cable runs through a plastic guide and the end is completely recessed so there is no purchase on it. The plastic is one moulded unit so there is no access to the cable.

I have tried lubricating it and pushing it through from the other end to no avail.

Many thanks!
Gill
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what's the silver nub in the last photo? is that the cable end?

Comment: It is. It is recessed in a plastic part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an "O" ring pick fails I used a small drill bit. First attempt is to drill a small hole in the (1/8 inch or smaller) cable anchor. Carefully try to start a small sheet metal screw into the drilled hole. pull on the screw with pliers. Method 2, drill a small hole through the plastic part just behind the anchor. Use an "O" ring pick to push the anchor out.

Comment: I will try the screw method. Thank you!

Comment: Needle nose pliers, a lot of patience and some soapy water.

Comment: So I tried the various methods but in the end the plastic casing broke. I picked up a replacement from Decathlon but I really don't like it. Not crisp clicks at all. It works though. I might try out a different one at some point. Thank you all!